# autologin from register page should be removed

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have an auth login control. Login form and register form all are working. I somehow kept my register form inside after login credentials. It is working inserting into user but needs to disable auto-login when registered.

Register controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    use RegistersUsers;    
    //protected $redirectTo = '/home';    
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255','unique:users'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'user_type' => ['required', 'string'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        ]);
    }

protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'user_type' => $data['user_type'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
        $this->guard()->login($data);

        return $this->registered($request, $data)
                    ?: redirect($this->redirectPath());
        Session::flash('flash_message','successfully saved.');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed few things it worked
in register controller i created new function

```
public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validator($request->all())->validate();
        event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));
        return $this->registered($request, $user)
            ?: redirect($this->redirectPath());
    }
```

Then added

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;
```

then removed

$this->guard()->login($user);

It is working now

Comment: Copying the work of the trait.. It is already done for you :) 
And your user is still logged in this way. You asked for disabling auto login.

Comment: yes i asked question then checked tried few things got the answer so i posted